# How to make loops in Python and in this script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have a script which is

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import pyaudio
import wave
from time import sleep
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE, input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print "recording..."
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
frames.append(data)
print "finished recording"




# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()
sleep(10)
```

which records my voice for 5 seconds and saves it in a wav file. Now to loop it I have tried adding the command

```
while invalid_input :
    start()
```

at the bottom of the script and the command `invalid_input = False` at the top of the script with no luck. Please make me understand how to loop this script when started; after the `sleep(10)` command. And also please cooperate with me as I am a newbie in python

Regards,

EDIT: I think I was not clear.
I want it that once it is started and reaches the end of the script, it again goes to the top and then does it again over and over till somone kills it

Comment: The spacing in your for loop is incorrect

Comment: @Mr.Helpy You need to indent lines in the loop

Comment: invalid_input will have to be True, and where is this start() function?

Comment: @hansn thanks for the tip and start function is what a friend told me so I just copy pasted his idea

Comment: @Xenon IS it mandatory? I was using Notepad++ so I think it should auto-Indent it

Comment: @Mr.Helpy Is it mandatory. Otherwise Python doesn't know what's in the loop and what's outside of the loop. You signal what's in the loop by indenting.

Comment: Python syntax needs you to indent your loops for 4 spaces in every loop, class declaration, method declaration. You NEED to fix your spacing on your for loop

Comment: @ryekayo OK I am sorry for being silly, but how would I do that?

Comment: By going to the next line after your for loop and pressing the space bar four times...

Comment: @ryekayo You mean after `while invalid_input `

Comment: @Mr.Helpy: No.  Each line that should be in the `for` block needs to be indented.

Comment: @zondo this one maybe? `for i in range`

Comment: @Mr.Helpy: Yes.  All lines that are meant to be included in that block should be indented by four spaces.

Comment: @zondo Ok thank you, done but is that suppose to loop now? because it is still not looping

Comment: Take a look at ryekayo's answer.  That is what your loop should look like.  If it doesn't loop, that means that `int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)` is `< 1`.

Comment: Lol Now it says Unexpected indent

Comment: Can you update your code in your question and indent it exactly as it is written in your python file?  As has been pointed out, what you have would have lots of problems.

Comment: Ok sure. As soon as I reach home that would be the first thing I will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a loop in Python, you need to indent properly. In your code, you have not indented correctly, per Python's convention:

```
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
    print "finished recording"
```

Comment: Ok done, but now it opens for a fraction of a second and closes

Comment: Can you add more details into your question about it? Your title and your questions don't exactly match

Comment: Sorry my bad i fixed it

Comment: Your loop seems to be counting from 0-8.. I don't think what you are doing is what you want to accomplish... I am guessing you need this loop to run for an extended period of time, correct?

Comment: I want it that once it is strated and reaches the end of the script, it again goes to the top and thens does it again over and over till somone kills it

Answer (score 1):

Alright, as mentioned in the comments, you NEED to indent. Python is a coding language that uses indentation instead of `end` or using `{}` ex:

> ```
> def function():
>     #Do stuff
> ```

Next, I'm not sure what `start()` is defined as but it won't by default start your script, you need to `def start():` and put the recording and saving script inside that function. And then you can call it later using `start()`

Lastly, your while statement is inverted. If you want to run the loop when `invalid_input` is false you need to `while invalid_input==False:`